# Find the number of files for each extension in a directory

Tags: command-line, find, extension

I want to count the number of files for each extension in a directory as well as the files without extension.

I have tried a few options, but I haven't found a working solution yet:

- `find "$folder" -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c` is an option but doesn't work if there is no file extension. I need to know how many files do not have an extension.
- I have also tried a find loop into an array and then sum the results, but at this time that code throws an undeclared variable error, but only outside of the loop:

  ```
  declare -a arr
  arr=()
  echo ${arr[@]}
  ```

  This throws an undeclared variable, as well as once the find loop completes.

Answer (score 15):

```
find "$path" -type f | sed -e '/.*\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*$/!s/.*/(none)/' -e 's/.*\.//' | LC_COLLATE=C sort | uniq -c
```

---

## Explanation:

- `find "$path" -type f` *get a recursive listing of all the files on the `"$path"` folder.*
- `sed -e '/.*\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*$/!s/.*/(none)/' -e 's/.*\.//'` *regular expressions:*

  - `/.*\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*$/!s/.*/(none)/` *replace all the files without extension by (none).*
  - `s/.*\.//` *get the extension of the remaining files.*
- `LC_COLLATE=C sort` *sort the result, keeping the symbols at the top.*
- `uniq -c` *count the number of repeated entries.*

Answer (score 9):

Using Python:

```py
import os
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

lst = []
for file in os.listdir('./'):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        lst.append(ext)

pprint(Counter(lst))
```

The output:

```
Counter({'': 7,
         '.png': 4,
         '.mp3': 3,
         '.jpg': 3,
         '.mkv': 3,
         '.py': 1,
         '.swp': 1,
         '.sh': 1})
```

Comment: You probably can get away with list comprehension, like   `ext = [  f.split('.')[-1] for f in os.listdir('./') ]`  Thatll make it couple lines shorter and perhaps more Pythonic

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I was just trying to write it as clear as I could ...

Comment: Clarity is the virtue :) Especially when it comes to code and engineering documentation.

Answer (score 6):

If you have GNU awk, you could do something like

```
printf '%s\0' * | gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"; FS="."; OFS="\t"} 
  {a[(NF>1 ? $NF : "(none)")]++} 
  END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}
'
```

i.e. construct / increment an associative array keyed on the last `.` separated field, or some arbitrary fixed string such as `(none)` if there is no extension.

`mawk` doesn't seem to allow a null-byte record separator - you could use `mawk` with the default newline separator if you are confident that you don't need to deal with newlines in your file names:

```
printf '%s\n' * | mawk 'BEGIN{FS="."; OFS="\t"} {a[(NF>1 ? $NF : "(none)")]++} END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}'
```

Answer (score 5):

With basic `/bin/sh` or even `bash` the task can be a little difficult, but as you can see in other answers the tools that can work on aggregate data can deal with such task particularly easy. One such tool would be `sqlite` database.

The very simple process to use `sqlite` database would be to create a `.csv` file with two fields: file name and extension. Later `sqlite` can use simple aggregate statement `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY ext` to perform counting of files based on extension field

```
$ { printf "file,ext\n"; find -type f -exec sh -c 'f=${1##*/};printf "%s,%s\n" "${1}" "${1##*.}"' sh {} \; ; }  > files.csv
$ sqlite3 <<EOF
> .mode csv
> .import ./files.csv files_tb
> SELECT ext,COUNT(file) FROM files_tb GROUP BY ext;
> EOF
csv,1
mp3,6
txt,1
wav,27
```

Comment: `files_tb` table I think is being referenced but the table columns are not defined anywhere I can see?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix They're defined in csv file itself. That's what the first `printf` does. And SQLite will default to treating first line of csv file as column names.

Comment: Very impressive! +1

Answer (score 5):

Using [PowerShell](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) if that's an option:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Group-Object Extension -NoElement
```

or shorter, using aliases:

```
ls -file | group -n Extension
```

Comment: Wow! Great first answer!  I didn't even know PowerShell existed for Linux... +1

Comment: Thanks. It has existed cross-platform and open-source for a while, but there's been a pattern on SO and SU where questions for shell scripting on Windows have often been answered with "Well, install cygwin and use bash, then you can do the following", so I've been hesitant to do the same for Linux SE sites with tools that originated on Windows. But this has been a nice task that shows PowerShell's strengths quite nicely without inviting the old argument about verbosity.